# Как правильно убрать параметры из URL запроса java ee?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, servlet, request

Я использую паттерн command. На странице jsp есть ссылка
a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller?command=go_to_log_in">Авторизация/a ,
где сервлету я передаю команду. В сервлете команда выполняется и происходит forward на другую jsp, но при forward URL не меняется и на странице авторизации будет URL ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller?command=go_to_log_in. Как правильно изменять данный URL на нужный. Может как-то в фильтре можно изменить request?

Comment: Нужный это какой?

Comment: Например на путь к нужной jsp

Comment: Этого делать не нужно, в некоторых случаях даже невозможно. Переход на страницу авторизации выполнен правильно, тут ничего менять не нужно.

Comment: Понял. Большое спасибо)